# MS-Word: How to work around bugs in Range.WordOpenXML / Range.InsertXML?

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, office-automation

Range.WordOpenXML seems appropriate for getting arbitrary Word content of a Range, and it should be possible to restore it in its original form using Range.InsertXML.

This often works, but fails in some cases: The restored content then differs from the original. See examples below. The problems occur in both VBA and .NET interop / VSTO.

Does anybody know if there is *a better, really **reliable** way* of saving and restoring the contents?

Or can you tell us how to work around the current odd behaviour which from our point of view are bugs?

Thanks in advance,

J.K

---

The simplest way to demonstrate the issue is VBA:

```vb
Private openXml As String

Public Sub Initialize()
  ThisDocument.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlRichText
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
  openXml = ThisDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.WordOpenXML
  ' The ContentControl's contents now are saved in openXML.
  
  ' After a possible intermediate manipulation of the content control we later
  ' want to restore the original contents:
  ThisDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.InsertXML openXml
End Sub
```

How to reproduce: Copy the code into an empty .docm. Run `Initialize()` to add a RichText content control. Add contents and/or formatting to the content control as specified below. Then run `Test()` to save and restore the content control's contents. Finally compare the restored contents to the original.

---

Examples of unreliability:

(1) A RichText ContentControl ("CC") containing a single paragraph including the terminating paragraph break: The retrieved WordOpenXML is equal to the one taken from a CC containing a single paragraph *without* the paragraph break. The result is not surprising: In both cases no paragraph break is restored after Range.InsertXML. In other words: WordOpenXML fails to extract the correct XML in the case where the original contents include the paragraph break.

(2) A CC containing a single image (and nothing else) is restored without the image, i.e. different from the original. If, however, it contains anything more than the image, there is no such problem.

(3) The previous examples apply if the page header section has never been visited. At least in VBA - I haven't checked it in depth with VSTO/interop - the behaviour changes once the insert position has been set into a page header: The restored contents then always contains a final paragraph break, even if the original hasn't had it. Saving and re-opening the document does not let Word forget the (mere) visit of the page header which obviously triggered this odd behaviour.

(4) If text formatting at the end of the content control is set to centered, right-justified or full-justified, an extra paragraph break is added upon restoration. This behaviour disappears as soon as you return to the default left justification.

Comment: Have you looked at storing information on the adding settings?

Comment: @Bouryepes: What exactly do you mean by "the adding settings"? And what information do you think of? If it is the contents of the content controls: The problem is not the place of storing, but the correct retrieval and restoration of the data.

Comment: Thanx for clarifying.